# Opposite font formatting

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, unicode, find-and-replace, text-formatting

I remember seeing somewhere an option to set the cursive, also called italics, formatting in such a way that, when applying it to the selected text, the value of every single character changes to its opposite, so that, in this case, originally italicized characters would turn into non-italicized ones. For example, applying it to

"... and *I* really *love* you, Sam."

would generate the output

"... *and* I *really* love *you, Sam.*"

In the case of bolding text, the result would be

"... and **I** really **love** you, Sam."

which after applying bold turns into

"... **and** I **really** love **you, Sam.**"

How can I get MSW to behave this way?
Hope to hear news soon.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have marked this as VBA, so, what have tried?

Comment: Perhaps a macro could get it done

Comment: Have you tried to write the macro and if so what have you tried?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea about how to command what I want I and I cannot find any clue on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a kludge, but…

Identify a font attribute that is not used in your document. 
I’ll assume that it is superscript. 
You could also use subscript, strikethrough, small caps, or whatever. 
To be safe, search for it with the “Find (and Replace)” dialog.

Then, using “Find and Replace”,

1. Find all italic text and change it to non-italic superscript.
2. Find all non-superscript text and change it to italic.
3. Find all superscript text and change it to non-superscript.

You could probably record a macro of this.